# How do you call a function from the component you are routing to?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that fires a function when you click on an icon.

ComponentOne.vue

```js
computed: {
      fields() {
        return [
          {
            icon: 'fa fa-file',
            action: ()=>this.$refs.myFunction.load()
          },
         ]
      }
    }
```

I want to link to ComponentOne from a second component, but I want it so that once ComponentOne has been loaded from the RouterLink, I want the function above to automatically fire without the user needing to click on the icon.
I know I could just change it so that the function would fire any time someone opened ComponentOne, but I ONLY want it to open automatically when I redirect users from ComponentTwo

ComponentTwo.vue:

```js
computed: {
      fields() {
        return [
                  {
          label: this.$t('name'),
          sortable: true,
          template: {
            type: 'link',
            action: () => this.showModal = false,
            label: data => data.item.userID,
            to: data => `/component-two/${data.item.id}
          }
        },
         ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Navigation Guards: In-component guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to define a navigation guard if and only if you go from component B to component A.

```js
 beforeRouteEnter(to, from) {
  // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
  // does NOT have access to `this` component instance,
  // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!
  if(from.name === 'Component B')
    //do something here!
},
```